# JNI: javah mangles arguments that are inner classes

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, javah

I have a JNI function that passes `android.graphics.Bitmap$Config` as an argument.  `Config` is an inner class of `Bitmap`.  When I run javah I get the incorrect header signature of (truncating to just the single argument):

```
Landroid_graphics_Bitmap_Config
```

which is the equivalent of:

```
Landroid/graphics/Bitmap/Config
```

instead of:

```
Landroid_graphics_Bitmap_00024Config
```

which is the equivalent

```
Landroid/graphics/Bitmap$Config
```

What javah generates is wrong as JNI will throw an error looking for the `_00024` representation of the `$` for the inner class.  The man for `javah` doesn't seem to imply any setting to correct this.  Is this just a limitation of `javah`?

Comment: Why would JNI be looking for the 0024 representation if javah doesn't generate it?

Comment: See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145897

Comment: @EJP An error is thrown loading the library in Android Studio, which defined that it was looking for the 00024 signature which I didn't have as I used the one directly from javah.  I imagine this is a java error, so its odd that javah doesn't generate the right signature.  The error message is what actually sent me on this wild goose chase.  Otherwise I would have had absolutely no idea about 00024/$.

Comment: @AlexCohn thanks, that confirms my suspicions I guess.  What is the relationship between OpenJDK and Oracle JDK?

Comment: OpenJDK is an open-source clone of Oracle (historically Sun) JDK. But the truth is that the same issue happens with Oracle JDK 1.8.0_77 on Mac. Note that if you run `javap -s` on your class, you will see the correct parameter descriptor.

Comment: @AlexCohn Thanks for all those details.  If you want to add that as an answer I'll select it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like, there is a bug <s>(or inconsistency, at least)</s> in JDK when parameters of inner class type are involved.

Here is a sample class that reproduces the problem:

```
public class A {

    public native void a(android.graphics.Bitmap.Config b);
    public native void a(android.graphics.Bitmap.Config b, int c);
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("hello-libs");
        a(null);
    }
}
```

If you use `javah` to generate the native header, you will get

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_example_hellolibs_MainActivity */

#ifndef _Included_com_example_hellolibs_MainActivity
#define _Included_com_example_hellolibs_MainActivity
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     A
 * Method:    a
 * Signature: (Landroid/graphics/Bitmap/Config;)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL A_a__Landroid_graphics_Bitmap_Config_2
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jobject);

/*
 * Class:     A
 * Method:    a
 * Signature: (Landroid/graphics/Bitmap/Config;I)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_A_a__Landroid_graphics_Bitmap_Config_2I
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jobject, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

and -

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void A.a(android.graphics.Bitmap$Config) (tried Java_A_a and Java_A_a__Landroid_graphics_Bitmap_00024Config_2)

But this bug rarely effects the headers generated by `javah` or `javac -h dir`, because usually the native methods are generated with 'short' names, e.g. `Java_A_a` which does not care about the type of parameter.

The solution is to manually change the method signatures, as suggested in https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145897.